# fancyBox3 - How to disable zooming when clicking opened image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

Good day.

I have such type of problem: when fancyBox gallery is opened and I just click on opened image (slide), image is zooming. I need to disable such behavior.

In documentation there is advice to use `clickContent` event for customizing behavior. I take example from documentation and initialize my copy of gallery by the next way:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    clickContent : function( current, event ) {
        // return current.type === 'image' ? 'zoom' : false;
        if (current.type === 'image') {
            return false;
        }
    },
    slideShow: false,
    fullScreen: false,
    thumbs: false
});
```

but `clickContent` override doesn't work. I have tried `console.log()` `clickContent` event:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    clickContent : function( current, event ) {
        // return current.type === 'image' ? 'zoom' : false;
        console.log('clicking test!');
    },
    slideShow: false,
    fullScreen: false,
    thumbs: false
});
```

but I didn't succeed.

Maybe I'm making a mistake somewhere. Please correct me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Update to v3.1 and use `clickContent` option to choose the action when user clicks on the content. Possible values:

```
"close"           - close instance
"next"            - move to next gallery item
"nextOrClose"     - move to next gallery item or close if gallery has only one item
"toggleControls"  - show/hide controls
"zoom"            - zoom image (if loaded successfully)
false             - do nothing
```

It can also be function that returns value from the list. Default value:

```
clickContent : function( current, event ) {
  return current.type === 'image' ? 'zoom' : false;
}
```

Also, your snippet works fine - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvNdJE

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstood me. I have problem **not** with **Open/close animation**. I want images not to zooming (by click on them) when gallery is open yet. I am hope for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the answer. And your snippet works, too. Make sure you are using v3.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I see your/my snippet works perfect. I will definitely check the version is 3.1. Thank you again for such wonderful library.